# Count Consecutive Leading 1's in Python int Binary Representation

Tags: python, binary

How can Python bit operations be applied to efficiently count up the number of consecutive leading 1's in an integer's binary representation.

*For instance,*

| ineger | binary representation | # consecutive leading 1's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0b0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0b1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0b10 | 1 |
| 3 | 0b11 | 2 |
| 4 | 0b100 | 1 |
| 5 | 0b101 | 1 |
| 6 | 0b110 | 2 |
| 7 | 0b111 | 3 |

This problem can be solved through string manipulation as `lambda x: f"{x:b}0".index("0")`, but I am looking for a bitwise operation without string conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up solving it myself.

```py
def count_leading_ones(n: int) -> int:
    all_ones_mask = (1 << n.bit_length()) - 1
    inverted = (n ^ all_ones_mask)
    return n.bit_length() - inverted.bit_length()
```

## Explanation

The key step is to invert the bits of n (switch 0's for 1's and vice versa).
When the leading 1's become 0's, they will no longer be picked up as part of `bit_length`.

We can then count how many sites fell of by subtracting `bit_length` after the inversion from `bit_length` before. This gives the number of leading 1's that were present.

## Examples

Here are leading 1's counts for 0 through 16,

```py
>>> for i in range(8):
...     print(f"{i} {bin(i)}: {count_leading_ones(i)}")
... 
0 0b0: 0
1 0b1: 1
2 0b10: 1
3 0b11: 2
4 0b100: 1
5 0b101: 1
6 0b110: 2
7 0b111: 3
```

## Performance Test

The bitwise method is about **30% faster**.

Here are the timings,

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> n = 123456
>>> bitwise = lambda: n.bit_length() - ((n ^ ((1 << n.bit_length()) - 1)).bit_length())
>>> stringify = lambda: f"{n:b}0".index("0")
>>> print("bitwise", timeit.timeit(bitwise, number=1000000))
bitwise 0.29356527600612026
>>> print("stringify", timeit.timeit(stringify, number=1000000))
stringify 0.3758607900090283
```

Comment: ah thats clever